# How to read a document in Firebase security rules?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to run a test on the simulator for some firebase security rules, but when running it, the resource is always shown as null and the test is never run for the allow write on the bottom level. Here's my code for the security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isSignedIn(); // only if user is signed in are they allow to do any operation
      
      match /{spaceId} { // Any space: not reading or writing allowed to those docs
            allow read, write: if false;
        }
        match /{spaceId}/posts/{postId} { // any post
            allow read; 
        allow write: if resource.user.uid == request.auth.uid;
        }
    }
```

[image: In this picture the innermost match isn't being checked against.]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `match /{document=**}` says that you're defining rules for this collection **and all documents under it**. So the top-level `allow` rule that checks `isSignedIn`, is also applied to all subcollections. And since rules are `OR`ed together, that means any signed in user can also read/write the `spaceid` documents.

To make the match only apply to its own collection, remove the `=**` from it.

Answer (score 1):

Frank have right you have vulnerability in rules. Rules are work like in css code i'm pretty sure. First restrict access to all data then allow to do any thing any one.

In example below users are only allowed to do some thing in users and app collection.

```js
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow create: if (isLoggedIn() && !userExist()) || isAdmin());
        allow read, update: if isOwner(userId) || isAdmin());
    }
    match /app/{data} {
        allow write: if isEditor();
        allow read: if true;
    }
}
```

**And solution for your question is `resource.data.user.uid` you miss data after resource. And remember there will be no resource if you create a document write operation is create and update. Update will work but no create.**

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. So afterwards, I tried doing an `allow delete: if (resource.data.user.uid == request.auth.uid)` But, I was given that "Property user is undefined on object", although I check that the path and the doc indeed exists.

Comment: @Andy Your `if` statement require to have already existing document with user.uid fields inside.

Comment: I don't know what you up to but i'm sure if you wanna have only this statement some one has to create document and it has to be backend with admin sdk. You can use firebase functions. look on my example of users collection. User are only able to create document if not allredy exist and request data id is equal to user uid.

Comment: Ok I understand the firebase functions, so does the doc you are trying to reference have to exist in your Firebase Emulator Firestore, or since I linked my existing firestore project will it be accessible? For some reason accessing an existing doc's data gives me this error. If you can reference my other question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528073/deleting-and-updating-docs-for-firestore-security-rules-in-local-emulator) I would highly appreciate it.