# Deleting and updating docs for firestore security rules in local emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-security

Using the local emulator, I'm trying to test a rule for my delete & update which looks like this:

```
match /posts/{postId} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow create: if true;
  allow delete, update: if (resource.data.user.uid == request.auth.uid)
}
```

In my test file, I write the path of the exact location of the existing doc that I'm trying to perform for example a delete on:

```
  it("If creator, Allow delete/update items in the post/comment collection", async () => {
    const db = firebase
      .initializeTestApp({ projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID, auth: myAuth })
      .firestore();
    const testDoc = db
      .collection("general")
      .doc("spaces")
      .collection("spaces")
      .doc("9LbUetZxWeL1ln5hv9ug")
      .collection("posts")
      .doc("RtUnezdAgXUfWmRSPpkF");
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.delete());
  });
```

However when I run this test, it gives me this error. However, I know this doc exists and so does the user.uid I am looking to grab in my resource. Is there something wrong in how I'm trying to use this emulator?

I also saw that if I go into my local emulator firestore database, I can hard-code a file, specifically call route my test to it, then it works.
[image]

Comment: Check are you connected to correct project. You say data exists and has `user.uid` property but response from database say there are no property `user`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like no user is signed in when you run the test.

Since your security rules check `request.auth.uid`, they reject the operation when `request.auth` is null. Check `myAuth.currentUser.uid` before running the test to ensure it has a value.

Comment: I have another test where I test if the doc id is that of the request.auth.uid which passes the test. So I believe that the issue is with the resource.data.user.uid.

Comment: A ? I have is, are my firestore that I linked different from that of the emulator firestore? Do I need to build out a similar database in my emulator firestore to that of the original?

Comment: "I believe that the issue is with the resource.data.user.uid" Given the error message, your security rules disagree with that statement. We might be missing context in the question of course, but I find it best to explicitly asset that there's a current user in my code so that it's beyond debate.